# How to call self component in Java swing?

Tags: java, swing, components, call, self

I have many buttons in a button group that need to search a database using their containing text as the query when toggled.

Instead of typing out specific event code for each button, how do I call a button's self?

Desired pseudocode:    `searchDB(genericSelf.getText())`

Tried using the `this` keyword and fiddling with getComponent, but I'm sure there exists a more efficient way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    JButton source = (JButton) evt.getSource();
    // source is your "this"
}
```

Comment: Wow, that was a fast response.  It works perfectly for this case!

Comment: What is the difference between mouseclick and actionperformed events ?

Comment: @Deepack they're from different listeners. `MouseListener` only listens to mouse events, but it can recognize if you clicked once or twice and can be plugged in to any component (label, panel, you name it). `ActionListener` is more abstract and used on all kinds of buttons and things that can trigger an action. Note that you can fire action on a button with keyboard as well - that's where `ActionListener` fires, but `MouseListener` doesn't.